# Increment Number in plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, plist

I am using the method below to get an array from my plist and then increase a certain value by 1, then save it. However I log the array and the value doesn't actually go up each time.

In my plist, I have an array and in that number values, each one is set to 0. So every time I run this again it goes back to 0 it seems.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Words.plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
    NSMutableArray *errors = [dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Errors%d.%d", [[stageSelectionTable indexPathForSelectedRow] section] +1, [[stageSelectionTable indexPathForSelectedRow] row] +1]];

    int a = [[errors objectAtIndex:wordIndexPath] intValue];
    a += 1;
    NSNumber *b = [NSNumber numberWithInt:a];
    [errors replaceObjectAtIndex:wordIndexPath withObject:b];

    [errors writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Any errors? Have you debugged your app allready? Do you know `NSLog()`?

Comment: No errors, I have used NSLog to track the errors array in my plist. It increments from 0 to 1, but then not from 1 to 2, it seems to revert back to 0, so presumably not saving, can't work it out.

Comment: I just figured out the mistake you made, read my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only write to a file in the documents-folder. **You can't write to your bundle!**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Namelist.plist"];
```

You can use `NSFilemanager` to copy your Plist-File to the documents-folder.

---

To get the path of your file:

```
- (NSString *)filePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile.plist"];
    return filePath;
}
```

To copy the file if it doesn't exist:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[self filePath]]) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"plist"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path toPath:[self filePath] error:nil];
}
```

Now you can write your **`NSDictionary`** to the Documents-Directory:

```
[dict writeToFile:[self filePath] atomically:YES];
```

**But you really need to update the array in the dict!**

Comment: So use this instead of my first two lines? I've tried and now my NSLog of the errors array just returns null.

Comment: Yes, but you need to copy your Plist-File first to the documents-directory if it doesn't exist. I'll gonna update my answer with some additional code.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing the *array* to disk, instead of the dictionary that the array originated from:

```
[dict writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
```

Also, you will need to replace the `Errors%d.%d` object with the updated one before saving it:

```
[dict setObject:errors forKey:/* your formatted key*/];
```

Finally, as @mavrick3 pointed out, you cannot save files to your bundle, only to your application's documents directory.

Comment: The OP still needs to save the dictionary, and not the array. There were several mistakes made here.